# Update table from one database with data from another database

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, sql-update, inner-join

Hello I have 2 MySQL databases on the same server with same structure and same data.
Occasionally data in one database are changed for 7 days and then should be back to the same value as in first database. Through PhpMyAdmin I am trying to write statement that should do thi but something I am missing. 
I have databases: db1_local and db2_local
Table gitem
column gbaseprice (should be synchronized from db1 to db2)
column gitemcode (has same value in both databases and synchronizing should be followed with this parameter so that id's don't mess up)
Appreciate any help

Here is statement
e.g. SQL statement that run in db2

```
UPDATE gitem
    SET gbaseprice=db1_local.gbaseprice 
FROM 
    db1_local.gitem(`gbaseprice`) 
    INNER JOIN db1_local.gitemtable 
    ON db1_local.gitem(`gitemcode`)=db2_local.gitem(`gitemcode`)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE db2_local.gitem G2
SET    G2.gbaseprice=
       (SELECT db1_local.gbaseprice G1
        FROM   db1_local.gitem
        INNER 
          JOIN db1_local.gitemtable 
        ON     G1.gitemcode=G2.gitemcode))
```